# CButton derived 'SubclassDlgItem's not visible on CDialogBar with VS2015 CLR, but respond to button clicks, worked fine in VC++ 6

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, cdialog, visual-studio-6

I'm trying migrate a VC++ 6 based code to work with VS2015 CLR.
I have major functionality working, but UI has some things missing.

There's a CDialogBar that hosts CWnd derived objects and CButton objects.
CWnd derived objects are being display fine, but CButton objects are all invisible, but operate normally when clicked blindly.

```
m_CWndDerivedObj.SubclassDlgItem(IDC_XXXXXX,this);
m_CButtonObj.SubclassDlgItem(ID_XXXXXX,this);
```

Another CDialogBar with no CButton objects is being displayed properly.

How may I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to resolve this by moving to using Custom button class derived from CWnd.
Original buttons were of type Command Button from Microsoft Forms 2.0.